# SQL Server 2014 IS_ROLEMEMBER returns NULL

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

The user exists:

```
select user_name(role_principal_id), user_name(member_principal_id) 
from sys.database_role_members
where user_name(member_principal_id) = 'CMICRO\Testsqluser'
```

the database role exists:

```
select user_name(role_principal_id), user_name(member_principal_id) 
from sys.database_role_members
where user_name(role_principal_id) = 'DeleteSN'
```

SQL Server 2014 IS_ROLEMEMBER returns NULL:

```
select IS_ROLEMEMBER ('CMICRO\Testsqluser', 'DeleteSN')
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/is-rolemember-transact-sql), the role comes first followed by the user.

```
select IS_ROLEMEMBER ('DeleteSN', 'CMICRO\Testsqluser')
```